# gdal_warp some geotiffs change SRS

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

Hello I#m quite new to GDAL. I have some Geotiffs that I want reproject.
I tried that with one file and it works great, but because the TIFF has to be slightly rotated for the conversion I have some black areas after that. This is Ok but I have not 1 I have arraound 100 Tiff files and when I built a simple loop with a gdal_warp command for every file I have 100 files with black areas. Is there another command or option where it takes the missing parts from next file ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Can you please **edit** your question and provide more information about your specific problem. Are you perhaps trying to **mosaic** adjacent images? What do you mean by "missing parts" and how are they related to the "next file"? Please also consider posting your loop so we can see if the error might be in your code.

Comment: There are many ways to handle the nodata areas. For example read again http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html and try -dstalpha. If you now open the warped images with QGIS the the black areas have turned into transparent. Some other programs can't deal with alpha channel but they want to know the nodata value -> try with -dstnodata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GDAL at the command line, you can build a virtual raster file to be used by gdalwarp or any other tool:

```
for %%N in (D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba %%N D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\%%~nN.vrt
gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index25.vrt NL25\*.vrt
```

The first line is only necessary if your data comes with paletted colours.

Comment: Thanks Andre, so steps are 1. Bulding a virtuell raster (vrt file) from all TIF files and 2. Add a parameter to my gdal_warp loop to let it know the vrt. Or ist there a commandline option like *.tiff for gdal_warp , too ?

Comment: You just use the vrt file (index25.vrt in my case)  as input for gdalwarp. No loop needed there.